# Is this thread safe and efficient in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

```
public class Test {

static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = null;
final static ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public static void open() {

    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        if (map != null) {
            return;
        }
        map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}

public static void close() {

    final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> concurrentHashMap;

    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }
        concurrentHashMap = map;
        map = null;
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }

    // deal with concurrentHashMap data
}

public static boolean put(final int key, final int value) {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        if (map == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map.putIfAbsent(key, value) != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean remove(final int key) {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        if (map == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map.remove(key) == null) {
            return false;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

In the code above, when put() and remove(), use readLock instead of writeLock, they are most frequently used.When open() and close(), both use writeLock, they are less frequently used. The target is to improve concurrency. I am not sure about:

1. Is it thread safe?
2. Is it efficient?

I think both is yes. I know ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe. I want to know if this implementation is good or bad and why.

Comment: The implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap` built in Thread safe and concurrent.

Comment: Why not make `map` itself `final`? Why do you want to deal with it being `null`?

Comment: The implementation does not seem to add anything, and now you have global locks around every `putIfAbsent` and `remove` that you do not have when using CHM directly, so I would say the implementation is bad.

Comment: The one thing the implementation does provide is an atomic `clear` (which I think CHM does not have). If that is important, maybe consider an `AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap>`. That can also be lock-free.

Comment: @KhalidShah, the purpose of the lock is to protect the `map` variable, not to protect the _contents_ of the map. Without the locking, the different threads could disagree on which `ConcurrentHashMap` instance was the _current_ instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Thread-safety:

It is thread-safe in one sense.  Once `close` has been called, further calls to `put` and `remove` won't affect the state of the map that `concurrentHashMap` refers to.

However, calls to `put` and `remove` before the next `open` will lead to lost updates.   That strikes me as poor design ... given that the ostensible point of `open` and `close` is to avoid losing updates.  This could be a thread-safety issue at another level.

### Efficiency:

On the one hand: I observe that all updates to the map are performed while you hold the lock.  Given that, I don't think there is any point in using a `ConcurrentHashMap`.   Using a regular `HashMap` would be thread-safe and more efficient.

On the other hand, since all updates are performed while holding the lock, the lock is a concurrency bottleneck, and the potential concurrency advantages of using a `ConcurrentHashMap` are moot.

---

I think I would implement this using an `AtomicReference` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)) ... and no lock.   The trick is to use `ref.getAndSet(new ConcurrentHashMap())` to "switch" the existing map for a new empty one.

The `AtomicReference` will still be a concurrency bottleneck, but to a much lesser degree, and you can avoid the "close ... open" hole by doing the two actions as a single atomic operation.

See @Holger's answer for an example solution using `AtomicReference` ... noting that his version doesn't address the "close ... open hole" problem.

Comment: 1. With the lock, I think can not use `HashMap`, because multi-thread will call the `put` method. 2. With the `AtomicReference`, can not "switch" the existing map for a new empty one, because when called `close` method, no one can call `put` any more until some one call `open`. 3. With the `AtomicReference`, you can not deal with the old data safely in `close`, because when you iterator the old `Map`, another thread may got the old `Map` reference, and is putting data to the old `Map`

Comment: If there are other threads using the map without using `open()` and `close()`  or acquiring the lock then your application is not thread-safe.   You should include **all** relevant code if you want an accurate answer to your question.  Please EDIT your question to add examples of how other threads are accessing / iterating / updating the map.

Answer (score 3):

As said by others, the efficiency can be improved by using an `AtomicReference` for this use case. But, what’s perhaps even more important, the code becomes much simpler:

```
static final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>>
    MAP = new AtomicReference<>();

public static void open() {
    MAP.compareAndSet(null, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
}

public static void close() {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = MAP.getAndSet(null);
    if(map != null) {
        // deal with map data
    }
}

public static boolean put(final int key, final int value) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = MAP.get();
    return map != null && map.putIfAbsent(key, value) == null;
}

public static boolean remove(final int key) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> map = MAP.get();
    return map != null && map.remove(key) != null;
}
```

Comment: You can not deal with the old data correctly in `close`, because when thread A iterator the old `Map` in `close`, thread B in `put` may got the old `Map` reference, and is putting data to the old `Map`. In this way, the new put data by thread B maybe not be touch in the `close` iterator by thread A

Comment: You are right, the atomic swapping of the current map with `null` doesn’t preclude threads already having the map. This could be fixed with an `AtomicStampedReference` which maintains the number of ongoing updates, but this wouldn’t be much different to using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.